# 2 Stacks In A Single Array Memory Efficiancy

Tags: arrays, data-structures, stack

This is a competitive quiz question that I faced. And I am not happy with the provided answer.

```
A  single  array  A[1..MAXSIZE]  is  used  to  implement  two  stacks.  
The  two  stacks grow  from  opposite  ends  of  the  array.
Variables  top1  and  top  2  (top1<  top  2) 
point to the location of the topmost element in each  of the  stacks.  
If the space is to be used efficiently, the condition for “stack full” is

(a)  (top1 = MAXSIZE/2) and (top2 = MAXSIZE/2+1)
(b)  top1 + top2 = MAXSIZE
(c)  (top1 = MAXSIZE/2) or (top2 = MAXSIZE) 
(d)  top1 = top2 -1
```

My logic was to start at both ends, therefore I went with answer (b) however the quiz has marked the answer (d) as correct. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First visualize the problem.  When you start with a few data points in each stack your array and tops may look like this (`MAXSIZE = 9`):

```
t1 = 2
t2 = 6
Array indexes: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Stack Tops:    |--t1          t2--------|
```

And when you're array is full of data `t1` and `t2` will be right next to one another like this:

```
t1 = 3
t2 = 4
Array Indexes: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Stack tops:    |-----t1 t2--------------|
```

---

Now lets look to see if any of the answers agree with the state of our array being full:

(a)  (top1 = MAXSIZE/2) and (top2 = MAXSIZE/2+1):

```
3 == 9/2  &&  4 == 9/2 + 1
3 == 4  &&  4 == 5
False
```

(b)  top1 + top2 = MAXSIZE:

```
3 + 4 == 9
7 == 9
False
```

(c)  (top1 = MAXSIZE/2) or (top2 = MAXSIZE):

```
3 == 9 / 2  ||  4 == 9
3 == 4  ||  4 == 9
False
```

(d)  top1 = top2 - 1:

```
3 == 4 - 1
3 == 3
True
```

D is the only answer that works.